# Does this code block the file?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

```
private Stream GetFileStream(String path) {
    return !File.Exists(path) ? null : File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
}
```

When tried and debugged, it looks like it is not blocking the file. But I'm not fully sure.

Comment: `But I'm not fully sure.` Why? just test it, whether is blocked(*whatever that means*) or not

Comment: I couldn't test it under concurrent access, like few people using the site at the same time. That is why i'm not sure.

Comment: ..You can have concurrent users reading the same file, they just cant write to it at the same time...

Comment: that is a read only file. I just need to read. no changes are made to that file at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you want you could add a fourth parameter to the File.Open method.

To open the file with read only access and allow subsequent opening of the file for reading:

```
private Stream GetFileStream(String path) {
    return !File.Exists(path) ? null : File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
}
```

This allows read and write:

```
private Stream GetFileStream(String path) {
    return !File.Exists(path) ? null : File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
}
```

This blocks this or other processes:

```
private Stream GetFileStream(String path) {
    return !File.Exists(path) ? null : File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
}
```

[File.Open Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: do I have to change anything in my current code if my case is only reading? the file will not be changed in any way. i just need to read.

Comment: I would add FileShare.Read in that case.

Comment: ok. that is logical. thanks.

Comment: @Ilham, not really related to your question, but using `File.Exists` before opening a file it's a pattern that should always be avoided. You can still get an exception if the file is read-only or you do not have the requested security permissions - and more importantly, since both operations are not atomic, what is going to happen if someone deletes the file just in that millisecond between the checking and opening with the file?

Answer (score 2):

The way your code works, it **does** block the file.

My understanding of block the file in this case is that it is in use by the first call to your `GetFileStream()` method, and any subsequent attempt to access the file will throw a `System.IO.IOException` because the file is already in use (until the stream is closed and disposed).

I'm not sure what test you did but here's a simple test where the second call to `GetFileStream()` will throw an exception:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new OpenFileTest("SomeFile.txt");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class OpenFileTest
{
    public OpenFileTest(string path)
    {
        var stream1 = GetFileStream(path);
        var stream2 = GetFileStream(path);  // throws IOException
    }

    private Stream GetFileStream(String path)
    {
        return !File.Exists(path) ? null : File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    }
}
```

If you want to just get the file as readonly and access it multiple times, why not change the method to read the file once using `File.ReadAllText()` or `File.ReadAllLines()` and store the result in memory?

```
private string[] GetFileLines(String path)
{
    return !File.Exists(path) ? null : File.ReadAllLines(path);
}
```

This method also guarantees you don't accidentally leave a bunch of FileStreams open, which need to be disposed.

If you cannot use memory and must return a stream, this way will handle it using `FileShare.Read`

```
private Stream GetFileStream(String path)
{
    return !File.Exists(path) ? null : File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
}
```

However note anytime you call that method, the calling method must dispose of the `Stream` object to prevent memory leaks.

```
// do stuff with stream;
stream1.Close();
stream1.Dispose();
```

Comment: then I need to change the code as @Ju9OR mentioned?

Comment: @Ilham: Depends on what you want - that's one way of doing it; I've shown another in my updated answer.

Comment: I can't use Memory for some reasons, if I explain it is too much talk. simply I can't use memory. all I can and I need is take the file stream, by not blocking the file for another process who also wants to take that file stream.

Comment: Gotcha, then yes FileShare.Read is the way to go as @Ju9OR mentions in his answer.

Comment: ok. thanks very much for confirming.